# How can I add where statement to Logic Apps SQL

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to get a row in Logic Apps from my SQL database. I need to get the latest record there type = 1. But, when you select the quick action "Get row" I only get to filter on id? I could not think of a more useless purpose...

[Link to describing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/praEk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "Get Rows"- action instead of "Get Row". 
"Get Rows" allows you to specify ODATA-filters.

For more information

[Sql Connector - Get Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#get_rows)

Alternatively, you could create a stored procedure which has Type as an input parameter and have this stored procedure return you the data you want. You can make sure the Stored Procedure only returns one row.

[SQL Connector - Execute Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute_stored_procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Get Rows action which allows you to specify your own filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#get_rows